# Open connected Wifi settings programmatically Android 10

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I worked on android app which I use Wifi, I need to get access to this view,

I use this code, but it's not working, I get the list of all wifi not the connected one

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

[image]

Comment: There are tens of thousands of Android device models. What that `Intent` displays will vary by model.

Comment: I look for the view of connected WIFI like this screen above, not the same, so which intent to use ?

Comment: There is no Settings `Intent` that absolutely guarantees anything across tens of thousands of Android device models.